# How to update existing value in table without inserting new using Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, insert-update, hibernate-onetomany

I have two tables one is parent and other one is child. When I am trying to save initially, I am able to insert values in both the tables if values not present in Parent table. But at the time of update/insert the values in child table, it is inserting duplicate values.

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RuleApi {
    Long id;
    private String market;
    private int modelYear;
    private String vehicleLine;
    private String vehicleLineName;
    private String locale;
    private String binding;
    private String description;
    private String createUser;
    private String updateUser;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DescriptorSaveRequest {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    RuleApi rule;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "MNAVS03_DESCRIPTOR_CONTEXT")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class DescriptorContext implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(name = "NAVS03_DESCRIPTOR_CONTEXT_K")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_MARKET_N")
    private String market;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_MODEL_YEAR_R")
    private Integer modelYear;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_VEHICLE_LINE_C")
    private String vehicleLine;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_VEHICLE_LINE_N")
    private String vehicleLineName;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_LOCALE_N")
    private String locale;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_CREATE_USER_C", nullable = false)
    private String createUserId;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "NAVS03_CREATE_S")
    private Timestamp createTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "NAVS03_LAST_UPDT_USER_C", nullable = false)
    private String updateUserId;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "NAVS03_LAST_UPDT_S")
    private Timestamp updateTimestamp;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "MNAVS04_DESCRIPTOR_RULE")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class DescriptorRule implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(name = "NAVS04_DESCRIPTOR_RULE_K")
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "NAVS03_DESCRIPTOR_CONTEXT_K", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private DescriptorContext descriptorContextId;

    @Column(name = "NAVS04_BINDING_N",
    unique = true)
    private String binding;

    @Column(name = "NAVS04_DESCRIPTOR_RULE_X")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "NAVS04_CREATE_USER_C", nullable = false)
    private String createUserId;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "NAVS04_CREATE_S")
    private Timestamp createTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "NAVS04_LAST_UPDT_USER_C", nullable = false)
    private String updateUserId;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "NAVS04_LAST_UPDT_S")
    private Timestamp updateTimestamp;
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Create/Update Feature Descriptions", notes = "Create/Update a descriptions based on the given input")
@PostMapping("/descriptor/saveFeatures")
public ResponseEntity<BaseBodyResponse<String>> saveFeatureDescriptions(@Valid @RequestBody DescriptorSaveRequest descriptorSaveRequest) throws Exception {
        this.descriptorContextService.saveFeatureDescriptions(
                this.descriptorContextMapper.mapDescriptorContext(descriptorSaveRequest),
                this.descriptorContextMapper.mapDescriptorRule(descriptorSaveRequest)
        );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(BaseBodyResponse.result("Saved Successfully"));
}

@Service
public class DescriptorContextService {
//SaveFeatureDescriptions
    public void saveFeatureDescriptions(DescriptorContext descriptorContext, DescriptorRule descriptorRule) throws Exception {
        DescriptorContext descriptorContext1 =
                this.descriptorContextRepository.findByMarketAndModelYearAndVehicleLineAndVehicleLineNameAndLocale(
                        descriptorContext.getMarket(),
                        descriptorContext.getModelYear(),
                        descriptorContext.getVehicleLine(),
                        descriptorContext.getVehicleLineName(),
                        descriptorContext.getLocale());
        if (descriptorContext1 == null) {
            // add a new context
            descriptorContext1 = descriptorContextRepository.save(DescriptorContext.builder()
                    .market(descriptorContext.getMarket())
                    .modelYear(descriptorContext.getModelYear())
                    .vehicleLine(descriptorContext.getVehicleLine())
                    .vehicleLineName(descriptorContext.getVehicleLineName())
                    .locale(descriptorContext.getLocale())
                    .createUserId(descriptorContext.getCreateUserId())
                    .updateUserId(descriptorContext.getUpdateUserId())
                    .build());
        }

        Long contextId = descriptorContext1.getId();
        List<DescriptorRule> rule = this.descriptorRuleRepository.findByDescriptorContextId(contextId);
        if (rule.size() == 0) {
            // add a new rule
            this.descriptorRuleRepository.save(DescriptorRule.builder()
                    .descriptorContextId(descriptorContext1)
                    .binding(descriptorRule.getBinding())
                    .description(descriptorRule.getDescription())
                    .createUserId(descriptorContext.getCreateUserId())
                    .updateUserId(descriptorContext.getUpdateUserId())
                    .build());

        } else {
            // update a existing rule
            for (DescriptorRule descriptorRule1 : rule) {
                if (descriptorRule1.getBinding().equals(descriptorRule.getBinding())) {
                    descriptorRule1.setDescription(descriptorRule.getDescription());
                    descriptorRule1.setupdateUserId(descriptorRule.getupdateUserId());
                    this.descriptorRuleRepository.save(descriptorRule1);
                }  else {
                        this.descriptorRuleRepository.save(DescriptorRule.builder()
                                .descriptorContextId(descriptorContext1)
                                .binding(descriptorRule.getBinding())
                                .description(descriptorRule.getDescription())
                                .createUserId(descriptorContext.getCreateUserId())
                                .updateUserId(descriptorContext.getUpdateUserId())
                                .build());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Component
public class DescriptorContextMapper {
        public DescriptorContext mapDescriptorContext(DescriptorSaveRequest descriptorSaveRequest) {
        return DescriptorContext.builder()
                .market(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getMarket())
                .vehicleLine(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getVehicleLine())
                .vehicleLineName(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getVehicleLineName())
                .modelYear(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getModelYear())
                .locale(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getLocale())
                .createUserId(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getCreateUser())
                .updateUserId(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getUpdateUser())
                .build();
    }

    public DescriptorRule mapDescriptorRule(DescriptorSaveRequest descriptorSaveRequest) {
        return DescriptorRule.builder()
                .id(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getId())
                .binding(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getBinding())
                .description(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getDescription())
                .createUserId(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getCreateUser())
                .updateUserId(descriptorSaveRequest.getRule().getUpdateUser())
                .build();
    }
}

{
  "rule": {
    "binding": "5003",
    "description": "Test new 5003-2023 Escape",
    "locale": "fr_CA",
    "market": "WANAC",
    "modelYear": 2023,
    "vehicleLine": "TMC",
    "vehicleLineName": "Escape",
    "createUser": "rdongre",
    "updateUser": "rdongre"
  }
}
```

If I am passing this request and values are not present in both the tables then it should insert the values in both the tables which is working as expected with above code. But at the time of update it is going inside the loop and inserting duplicate values. I am trying to update DESCRIPTION in child table if BINDING is present if not it should insert BINDING plus DESCRIPTION

Comment: Most of this code is not needed and makes the question not readable

Comment: What should I remove to make it readable?

Comment: Minimal example that can be reproduced will be great: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If the id is set then the existing record should be updated. If it is not set it should create a new record. I do not see where you set the id on the entity before you save?

Comment: I have id columns in both the table:
Parent table: name = "NAVS03_DESCRIPTOR_CONTEXT_K")
    private Long id;

Child table:  (name = "NAVS04_DESCRIPTOR_RULE_K")
    private Long id;

    JoinColumn(name = "NAVS03_DESCRIPTOR_CONTEXT_K", nullable = false)
    ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private DescriptorContext descriptorContextId;

Comment: @Andronicus I am not able to edit the question in order to make it readable.

Comment: Yes, it's in your table definition. But where do you *set* it on the entity before saving? If you don't set your id, how is it supposed to know which record to update? (answer: it doesn't, so it creates a new one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by separating Save and Update methods. Thanks to all.